# Can I enter an airport terminal, go to a departure gate, then go to a different terminal?

Tags: air-travel, airports, airport-terminals, customs-and-immigration, fco

I travel with my wife from Rome. Due to technical reasons, we have to take different flights. My flight goes out from FCO airport terminal 1, while her flight goes out from FCO terminal 3, at approximately the same time. Since she does not speak English/Italian and is quite anxious about being alone, I want to go with her all the way to the departure gate in terminal 3, and then go back to terminal 1 to take my flight. Is it possible?

On the map, it is only 7 minutes walk, so technically it should be easy. My main concern is the passport control - if I go through passport control at terminal 3, I am formally outside of Italy. Will I be able then to go back into Italy to go to terminal 1?

Are there any other potential problems in this plan?

Comment: A map of [FCO](http://www.adr.it/documents/10157/109482/overview_partenze_21032018.PDF/935698bc-2bbe-4f08-94ce-565afcf75043) shows no sign of any airside connection between T1 and T3. There _might_ be some way to go _back_ through passport control, get stamped _into_ Italy again, and then leave immediately, but I think this is just not a great idea. You may have trouble with security when you try to go through at the 'wrong' terminal. I would prepare her for what gate she needs to find without you.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Looking at Google it would appear to me that there is an airside connection.  See https://www.google.com/maps/place/Leonardo+da+Vinci+International+Airport/@41.8001071,12.257407,291a,35y,209.41h,60.67t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xafe513b4e358316f!8m2!3d41.7998868!4d12.2462384

Comment: @PeterM Connections like that may only go from Arrivals to Departures, for transfer pax. That's often a one-way path. If he can get to the arrivals area in T3, he _may_ be good, but that must involve going through passport control if he has been stamped out.

Comment: " I am formally outside of Italy" Not yet, no. You'll be outside of Italy when your plane takes off. Until then, you're still in Italy.

Answer (score 5):

Some airports will give you a “gate pass” which allows you to accompany a passenger to the departure gate (or from the gate for returning passengers).  It’s mostly used for children or elderly passengers.

You can ask at the ticket counter if you can have one. Especially since your wife is passing through a sterile transit or emigration area, it’s unlikely in your case that you’ll get one. But you can still ask - and might want to ask on the phone ahead of time.

Otherwise, using a smartphone with video chat (FaceTime, Skype video, line, etc) can be a good way to guide her. Note she’ll have to turn off her video phone while in security.

Comment: I tend to doubt the gate pass will get him through the Schengen exit control; and if it does, he now has to wander a non-standard route in the terminal to come through _arrivals_ and be re-admitted to Schengen for a few minutes while he changes terminals and goes to his own flight.